# NodeJS Module to help generate files

Tags: javascript, node.js, scaffolding

I'm looking for a nodejs module to use in my project that will generate files and directories.

To give some background, my node project makes use of certain user made widgets, each of which has a very specific configuration and file layout. I want a simple way of generating these skeleton files for the user, using some of the info they input as parameters

#### Desired Workflow

```
$ mymodule make new widget
What kind of widget do you want? (dbquery, htmlquery)
> dbquery
What name do you want to give to your widget?
> samplename
In which directory are your widgets located?
>  /home/name/Code/dashboard/widgets
...generating samplename dbquery widget *(creates a couple of folders and files with some basic content)*
DONE!

$
```

Comment: It sounds like you want a scaffolding wizard of some sort. Scaffolding is creating a consistent set of files from templates, and the wizard is where you prompt the user for information. However, it sounds like you need to write this yourself, as it's doubtful anyone has just created such a framework.

Comment: I'm interested in creating a project like this as well. As I have not found any contact details in your profile, could you please contact me? Then we might discuss some ideas or ways to work with each other. For contact details, see my profile http://stackoverflow.com/users/1333873/golo-roden ... you'll find my email address there. Looking forward to hear from you :-)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The core [fs](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_file_system) module can create files and directories.

Use the module

```
var fs = require('fs');
```

Create a file:

```
fs.writeFile('message.txt', 'Hello Node', function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('It\'s saved!');
});
```

Create a directory:

```
fs.mkdir('test', function(err) {
  console.log('done');
});
```

Another cool module is [mkdirp](https://github.com/substack/node-mkdirp). Works like `mkdir -p`. The content of your skeleton files can either be stored in a js variable/string and then be written to the users' files or you could use some dummy files and read the content from there:

```
fs.readFile('/widget/layout.conf', function (err, data) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I started a project similar to what you have been asking for. It's a Node.js module that can be installed globally that scaffolds modules and / or applications based on a GitHub repositories.

See [nudo](https://github.com/thenativeweb/nudo) for details.